# node.js http server how to get connections count

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node as a http server with the following code:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {}).listen(8181);
```

I'm looking for a simple way to monitor a node js http server from within the same process. For me it would be enough to have a own function which just outputs the current resource usage and connection count as json. For now I don't need deep measuring or real time performance monitoring.

What are the key performance indicators for a node http server and is it possible to get them from node? If yes how? 
What you think of the folling kpi's:

1. Connection Count
2. CPU Usage
3. Ram Usage

Just need to know which variables/functions I need to get the data?

Thx I really appreciate your help

Comment: is there any connection time out callback? How to handle it? It may just be enough for me to now whether I ever reached a connection limit.

Answer (score 23):

You can get the amount of connection using a built in function of NodeJS. Check [getConnections](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_getconnections_callback). Bellow an example how to use it:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);    

server.getConnections(function(error, count) {

    console.log(count);

});
```

I hope this is what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

You need something like this:

```
var count = 0;

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    count++;
    res.on('finish', function () {
        //setTimeout(function () {
        count--;
        //}, 60000);
    }).on('close', function () {
        count--;
    });
}).listen(8181);
```

With `setTimeout()` you can get the active connections in the last 1 minute.

see http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_cpus for CPU usage

see http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage for memory usage

Comment: thx @micnic. helped me a lot. If I implement http.setTimeout(time, callback). How do I have to close the http socket?

Comment: @Manuel, there is no `http.setTimeout(time, callback)`, use the usual `setTimeout(callback, timeout)` and add inside the callback function only the counter variable

Answer (score 1):

[**scribbles**](https://npmjs.com/package/scribbles) is a logging module I created.

You can just drop in you project and get **CPU**, **Mem** & **Net** out of the box + more some other handy flags & metrics.

**Checkout the [performance-monitoring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scribbles#performance-monitoring) part.**

To use:

```
const scribbles = require('scribbles');

scribbles.config({
   dataOut:console.log
})

setInterval(function(){
  scribbles.status();
}, 5000);

// This will give you a performance snapshot every 5 seconds.
```

**You get:**

- network: *Networking info*

  - port: *listening on this Port*
  - connections: *number of current established connections*
- state: *the state of the services. e.g. "up", "blocking"*
- cpu: *CPU info*

  - cores: *number of available cores*
  - model: *description of the processor*
  - speed: *MHz frequency speed*
  - percUsed: *load on process as percentage*
  - percFree: *available on process as percentage*
- sys: *System info*

  - startedAt: *when it's system was started*
  - arch: *platform architecture. e.g "x64"*
  - platform: *the operating system platform*
  - totalMem: *the total megabytes of memory being used*
  - freeMem: *the total megabytes of memory free*
  - usedMem: *the total megabytes of memory being used*
- process:

  - percUsedCpu: *the percentage of processing power being used by this process*
  - percFreeMem: *the percentage of memory being used by this process*
  - usedMem: *the total megabytes of memory being used by this process*
  - startedAt: *when it's process was started*
  - pTitle: *the current process title (i.e. returns the current value of ps)*
  - pid: *the ID of the process*
  - ppid: *the ID of the current parent process*
  - user: *node the name of the user who started node*
  - vNode: *version of node*

Comment: While the intentions behind this are good, in real world this is better served by having Prometheus + Grafana installed in your cluster, and then using Epimetheus npm package to scape Express-specific metrics (and scrape normal Kubernetes information about nodes and pods, for CPU/RAM usage).

Comment: In this case, this is just a drop in module with zero config and if that works for some people, thats fine. 
Else they are welcome to invest the time to make a more comprehensive logging system as you suggest. It all depends on what architecture someone want to achieve and what services at what level should have what responsibilities they are happy with.